# How to Design an acceptor for integers in a programming language C

Tags: automation, finite-automata, automata, formal-languages

I was reading a book named "An introduction to Formal Languages and Automata" by Peter Linz. In one of it's questions, it asked me to, `"Design an acceptor for integers in a programming language C"` Can some one please tell me how can I obtain an answer for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since your book is about automata, I'm guessing that they want you to write a finite state machine. You can do a search for how to write an FSM in C; here is [one example](http://ankurs.com/2010/04/simple-finite-state-machines-in-c/).

Comment: I have difficulties following c code. Do you know any good example to implement this in c# or java? I need some help in a similar exercise, I need to implement a FSM in c#, the FSM role is acceptor (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Acceptors_and_recognizers)